# Homebrew suggests there's always an existing formula for node installed?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, symlink

I am trying to install **node** to use with **reactjs**. I started with **node 16** but found it was incompatible with **node-sass**, so I've downgraded to **node 14**.

When installing (`brew install node@14`), it remains keg-only as it says:

```
node@14 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.
```

**Node 16** had been installed with `brew install node` and uninstalled with `brew uninstall node`. I've ran `brew cleanup`, I've uninstalled and reinstalled brew via the official uninstall script. When I run `brew info node` it says:

```
node: stable 16.3.0 (bottled), HEAD
Platform built on V8 to build network applications
https://nodejs.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/node.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✘, python@3.9 ✘
Required: brotli ✘, c-ares ✘, icu4c ✔, libuv ✘, nghttp2 ✘, openssl@1.1 ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 345,586 (30 days), 1,126,089 (90 days), 4,391,805 (365 days)
install-on-request: 271,229 (30 days), 880,350 (90 days), 3,293,366 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Which, in my limited understanding, suggests 16 is not installed.

What is causing node to say there's already a formula for **node** installed and it must keep v14 in keg-only mode? I'm on macos mojave and I don't believe there's any included node that would conflict? Running `brew list` shows node isn't present.

---

### Updates

I ran **brew bundle dump** and it gave:

```
tap "homebrew/bundle"
tap "homebrew/core"
brew "node@14"
```

... which again, I don't quite understand why installing node@14 ends with a keg-only install because it states that "*this is an alternate version **of another formula**.*"

The only thing I can think of now is that the other formula is referring to the fact that 14 is not the default release (which is now 16) whether the latest is installed or not?

But this also doesn't make sense to me as I'd imagine a simple y/n warning that a newer release exists would be more beneficial rather than making 14 not work on the command line without manual intervention that I'm hesitant to do.

---

Running `brew doctor` states:

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1.


Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
```

I couldn't see anything noteworthy in the lib folder other than 'node_modules' that I'm unsure of what build it came from. I tried removing it temporarily and reinstalling node@14 but the same problem remains.

Comment: `node@14` will ALWAYS install keg-only since it's not the current version. Like one of the answers says, you can manually link it using `brew link`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
brew link node@14
```

You can have both versions installed and switch with the above (change @14 to @16). Since you initially installed v16, your symlinks are pointing there, so run above to reset the correct v14 you are looking to use.

As suggested above, you can use `nvm`to manage different node versions, but I personally have found it much easier to use `brew link` to easily change between versions rather. [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) is another popular one, but again, my personal choice is`brew`. Colleagues prefer `n`, so take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage multiple node installation.

Install it with:

```
brew install nvm
```

Create the `nvm` directory:

```
 mkdir ~/.nvm
```

Install the version you want:

```
nvm install 14
```

You can then list your available versions with `nvm ls` and list all available commands with just `nvm`.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew link node@16
brew link --overwrite node@16
```

use brew to relink the version 16, and then we need to force the link and overwrite all conflicting files.